# Restful authentication and authorization

Tags: php, rest, authentication, restful-authentication

I'll build a single page web app (with Backbone js) and make it consume a Restful API (in PHP) that I've to build too.

I wonder how to handle my user authentication to the API and manage the authorization when user request some data ?

I know that a restful api should be stateless but I'm stuck at this point.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The authentication is easy.

You can handle sessions as resources:

```
POST /sessions {email, password}
-> {userId, token}
```

After that you can send back the token in a http header or in a cookie (better in http header because it protects you from CSRF attacks). I the service does not get token in the request header, than it can send back a 401 unauthorized response. If you cannot create the session, you can send back a 4** request, I use to send back 404 not found.

The authorization is harder.

You have to decide how granular you authorization system should be. It can be ACL, RBAC, ABAC, depends on how complicated your application and your access rules are. Usually people use ACL and RBAC hardcoded like this (fictive language):

```
@xml

    role 1 editor

@/articles

ArticleController
    @GET /
    readAll () {
        if (session.notLoggedIn())
            throw 403;
        if (session.hasRole("editor"))
            return articleModel.readAll();
        else
            return articleModel.readAllByUserId(session.getUserId());
    }
```

It works fine by simpler systems, but with this approach you will never have clean code because the access control should not be part of the business logic, you should externalize that. You can do that with an ABAC system, for example with an XACML implementation. (XACML is a great tool, but I find it a bit complicated.) You can create a custom automatic ABAC system with this approach too (same example):

```
@db

    role 1 editor
        policy 1 read every article
            constraints
                endpoint GET /articles
            permissions
                resource
                projections full, owner

    role 2 regular user
        policy 2 read own articles
            constraints
                endpoint GET /articles
                logged in
            permissions
                resource
                projections owner


@/articles

ArticleController
    @GET /
    readAll () {
        if (session.hasProjection(full))
            return articleModel.readAll();
        else if (session.hasProjection(owner))
            return articleModel.readAllByUserId(session.getUserId());
    }
```

Comment: Note: if you have multiple deliveries, not just REST (for example SOAP, web application, flash, and so on), then it is better to describe the authorization logic with domain terms, and not with delivery terms, like URIs, etc...)